# Actionbar moving tab indicator

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using `ActionBar` of `AppCompact` with tabs and `ViewPager`.
How can I implement moving (with the fragment) tabs indicator like in Onavo app?
I tried to use `PagerTitleStrip` but didn't succeed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library called "PagerSlidingTabStrip" that does exactly what you want: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

> Interactive paging indicator widget, compatible with the ViewPager from the Android Support Library.

**Usage**

Include the PagerSlidingTabStrip widget in your view. This should usually be placed adjacent to the ViewPager it represents.

```
<com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
   android:id="@+id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />
```

In your onCreate method (or onCreateView for a fragment), bind the widget to the ViewPager.

```
 // Set the pager with an adapter
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

 // Bind the widget to the adapter
 PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
 tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

(Optional) If you use an OnPageChangeListener with your view pager you should set it in the widget rather than on the pager directly.

```
 // continued from above
 tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
```