# Smooth Moving ActionBar Indicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have the same question as: [Actionbar moving tab indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521368/actionbar-moving-tab-indicator) 

In the above question's answer, he recommend to use a third party library. I'm wondering if there's any approach without using external lib? Or if there's any built in support of this in `actionbarsherlock`?

Thank you

Comment: "I have the same question as: Actionbar moving tab indicator" -- that question is about tabs for a `ViewPager`, and the solution is a tabbed indicator for that `ViewPager`. Despite the question title, it is not really about action bar tabs.

Comment: Apologize for my uncleared title. @CommonsWare can you please point me the solution?

Comment: The solution is to use `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator that offers your smooth movement. If `PagerTabStrip` does not have what you want, use the library. I avoid action bar tabs, as they change into a drop-down list in various circumstances.